# gcc 4.8 on MacOS fails depending on -arch order

Tags: macos, gcc

I am trying to get a recent version of gcc 4.8.2 up on my machine. I have tried installs that come from MacPorts as well as the one that gets installed alongside the binary install of gfortran.

For a minimal source file, I get errors depending on the order of the -arch flags.

Specifically,  `-arch x86_64 -arch i386` (or either of them alone) works:

```
% /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 conftest.c
% /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -O3 conftest.c
```

But `-arch i386 -arch x86_64` fails:

```
% /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 conftest.c
/var/folders/6l/7gzvw1zs42sbhj7_hlrpykfm0000gv/T//cc6JCBdP.s:5:bad register name `%rbp'
/var/folders/6l/7gzvw1zs42sbhj7_hlrpykfm0000gv/T//cc6JCBdP.s:7:bad register name `%rsp'
/var/folders/6l/7gzvw1zs42sbhj7_hlrpykfm0000gv/T//cc6JCBdP.s:10:bad register name `%rbp'

% /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -O3 conftest.c
/var/folders/6l/7gzvw1zs42sbhj7_hlrpykfm0000gv/T//ccs67E0q.s:34:FATAL:Bad fx_size (0x8) in fix_to_relocation_info()
```

Help!

The minimal source:

```
 int main ()
 {
  return 0;
 }
```

For info:

```
% /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 --version
gcc-mp-4.8 (MacPorts gcc48 4.8.2_0+universal) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

`gcc`/`g++` as distributed by its developers does not support multiple `-arch` flags simultaneously. Only the Apple-modified versions of `gcc`/`g++`, for example those distributed by Apple with Xcode versions earlier than 4.2, support that.

To compile for multiple architectures using a non-Apple `gcc`/`g++`, compile for each architecture separately, then combine the results using `lipo`.

```
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 -arch x86_64 -o conftest-x86_64 conftest.c
/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 -arch i386 -o conftest-i386 conftest.c
lipo conftest-x86_64 conftest-i386 -create -output conftest
```